# Viewing XML request and response in web services call

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm consuming a third-party web service in an ASP.NET webforms application.  I simply added a web reference to the provided WSDL and coded up a basic call to the service from my code-behind.  The provider of the web service requires that we send the XML for the request and response for approval.  However, I don't know how to accomplish that.  My first instinct was to use Fiddler.  But Fiddler can't see the actual XML going over the wire due to the security features of the web service.  Several blog posts suggest modifying the WSDL, but this doesn't seem like a good thing to do since the provider of the web service would surely prefer that it be left intact.  So my question is, what is the simplest and most direct way to capture the XML request and response for a secure web service? If the answer is Fiddler, please tell me how to do this since all I'm seeing are the encrypted calls.

EDIT --- here's the specific implementation of the security policy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;


namespace ShipWSSample
{
    public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
    {
        public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
        { }

        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp,
         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, int problem)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Must you use a web reference? If you use a service reference, then you can use WCF tracing trivially to show you exactly what's happening. Otherwise, see "SoapExtension".

Comment: I probably could have used a service reference.  But it's a little late in the game to switch.  This being my first time working with a provided WSDL I made the wrong choice.

Comment: Not that big a difference. In general, just "don't do that" with the use of a web reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two levels of data encryption while consuming the service:

1. Channel-level encryption, when the complete communication is encrypted, for example by using HTTPS protocol.
2. Message-level encryption, when every message sent through the service is encrypted individually using public key architecture or some other open-key algorithms.

In the first case you can use Fiddler2 to decrypt the HTTPS traffic using a sort of "man-in-the-middle" attack on its proxy. [Here are more details](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) on it.

Comment: I think it's the former.  Please see my edit above for the security policy implementation.